# Beginner / How to configure my .htaccess file so that it runs the PHP inside my HTML files?

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

So I'm trying to configure my `.htaccess` file so that it can runs the PHP code inside the HTML files.

When I go to `mysite.com/thefile.php`, it runs it correctly without any problem. Same if I go to `mysite.com/thefile.html`. But if I add `<?php echo "Hello"; ?>` inside the HTML file, it doesnt display anything. In fact, when I right click "View source code", it displays the php lines.

Here's what I tried with my `.htaccess` file:

> RemoveHandler .html .htm
>
> AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html .htm

I also a tried with just

> AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html .htm

But it displays a "500 Internal Server Error" that says:

```
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. 

The most common causes of this problem are errors in the app's .htaccess file or incorrect file or directory permissions preventing the web server from reading the .htaccess file. 

More information about this error is available in the app's Apache error log at:

/srv/users/SYSUSER/log/APPNAME/APPNAME_apache.error.log
```

I'm quite new to web development in general, and I want to mention that, except from these 2/1 lines in the .htaccess file, I have nothing else. Maybe I'm missing some lines in it? Just a guess

Thanks guys (and gals if they exist!)

Comment: Don't do it! What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm just trying to display info's from my Databse in my HTML file

Comment: Do it from your PHP file.

Comment: Which version of apache and which flavor/version of linux?

Comment: You need AddHandler, not AddType.

Comment: p.s. gals exist.

Comment: @jgvk what's the status of this question? If the answer given below solved it, you should consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Ubuntu/Apache 2.4.x, in your `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.1.conf` or equivalent, you could add:

`<FilesMatch ".+\.html$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>`

(But you shouldn't do this at all! Use .php files for PHP code.)

Comment: What's so bad about executing PHP in .html files? Not arguing, just curious about your rationale.

Comment: There's already an extension dedicated to PHP. Why pollute another file extension and force every piece of static content through the PHP interpreter? What happens when your site grows and you move it to a new server and forget to add that configuration? Now all your PHP code (include DB usernames and passwords) are exposed until you fix it. What happens if you do an apache upgrade and accidentally wipe that configuration and have to go find the backup to restore? Everything is temporarily exposed again.